# How can I run code upon session death with Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I would like to run code whenever a Yesod session dies. For example whenever a session dies I would like to print "hello" to the console.

I did not use the scaffolding for my application.

Comment: Are you referring to sessions of the sort described [in this chapter](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/sessions) of the Yesod book?

Comment: yes this is what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesod's default sessions are done with `clientsession`. This works by storing encrypted data in the cookies from the browser—the server doesn't store any state. For this reason, I don't think there's a way to accomplish what you want.

You could switch to some sort of server-stored session, in which case you could *kinda* do this based off a session expiring, though you'd never be able to detect something like "the user cleared their cookies" which effectively kills a session.